# char list list -> bool

Tags: sml

Does anyone know how to declare  a function

> rscheck : char list list -> bool

, that checks,  if the number 1-9 are used once in every row and every list... so it returns true?

like in a sudoku game..

Thnx.

Comment: I havn't any sepciel idea yet... 
something like fun rschek xs = ....

Comment: The functions defined in the answer to [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946390/help-sml-troubled) should help you get started.

Answer (score 2):

It could be done like this (also there is a better way for sure, just some training for me):

http://pastebin.com/ViJM48LV